# MVC drop down list: Setting class name and default selected item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, selecteditem

I have a drop down using

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.param, new SelectList
      (Model.MyList, "Value", "Text"), "Select")
```

This sets the first item of list to "select".  I have two questions:
Can I assign a class to this drop down as well as the selected value? I tried

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.param, new SelectList
      (Model.MyList, "Value", "Text"), new{@class="clname", @value="Select")
```

but it does not work

Also, can I set a value to the default text `select` so that its value will not be an empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I load my select lists in a controller. So it comes onto the page as part of the viewmodel.

The following will load the drop down with a css class `clname` and the first option will be `"-- Select --"`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.param, 
          Model.MySelectList, 
          "-- Select --", 
          new { @class = "clname"})
```

> Also, can I set a value to the default text select so that its value
>   will not be an empty string?

For this, you should load the select list in the controller with the appropriate values.

ViewModel:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public string MyParam {get;set;}
    public List<SelectListItem> MySelectList {get;set;}
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
          var model = new HomeViewModel();
          // to load the list, you could put a function in a repository or just load it in your viewmodel constructor if it remains the same.
          model.MySelectList = repository.LoadMyList();
          model.MyParam = "Select"; // This will be the selected item in the list.
          return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyProject.HomeViewModel

<p>Select:
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MyParam, 
          Model.MySelectList, 
          new { @class = "clname"})
</p>
```

Hope that makes it clear.